# Multiple relations of same type

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.2

For my models, I have `RealEstateTransaction` and `Agent`. A `RealEstateTransaction` can have a `ListingAgent` and a `SellingAgent`.

How would I build out my models to make that relation? Something like this?

```
public class Agent
{
    public long AgentId { get; set; }

    public List<RealEstateTransaction> ListingRealEstateTransactions { get; set; }

    public List<RealEstateTransaction> SellingRealEstateTransactions { get; set; }
}

public class RealEstateTransaction
{
    public long RealEstateTransactionId { get; set; }

    public long ListingAgentId { get; set; }
    public Agent ListingAgent { get; set; }

    public long SellingAgentId { get; set; }
    public Agent SellingAgent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Something like this?

Indeed.

But it requires some additional mapping of the navigation properties (the FK property names follow the EF Core conventions, so no mapping is required for that). Normally EF Core is able to pair the navigation properties of the two ends of the relationship, but not when you have two relationships to one and the same entity. In such case you need to tell which navigation property of the principal corresponds to (is inverse of) the each navigation property in dependent.

Normally you can do that by either data annotation (`[InverseProperty]` attribute) or fluent API. But since more than one FK relationships to the same entity also introduce the so called *multiple cascade paths* issue with SqlServer (and some other databases), you'd need also to turn the cascade delete off for at least one of the relationships, and this can be done only with fluent API, so the minimal mapping required is something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Agent>()
    .HasMany(e => e.ListingRealEstateTransactions)
    .WithOne(e => e.ListingAgent)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<Agent>()
    .HasMany(e => e.SellingRealEstateTransactions)
    .WithOne(e => e.SellingAgent)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

You can skip `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)` for one of the relationships (or change it to `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` which is the default for required relationships like these). Note that deleting the principal (`Agent` in this case) will require first manually deleting all the related dependents for each relationship having  `DeleteBehavior.Restrict`.

That's the mandatory part. Optionally, if the `RealEstateTransaction` entity serves only as standard many-to-many "link" entity (has no additional properties and the pair `(ListingAgentId, SellingAgentId)` is unique), you could remove the `RealEstateTransactionId` PK property and configure fluently a composite PK:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RealEstateTransaction>()
    .HasKey(e = new { e.ListingAgentId, e.SellingAgentId });
```

**References:**

- [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)
- [Keys (primary)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys)

Comment: Thorough answer, thank you! I came to the same conclusion after reading more documentation. I hadn't yet come to the issue of the DeleteBehavior, so that's good to note. You could probably imagine that there will be cases where there are multiple transactions where the same agent combination could work on multiple sales together, so, in this scenario, it would not be a good idea to use the agents' IDs together as a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

do this :

```
public class Agent
{
    public long AgentId { get; set; }

    public Virtual ICollection<RealEstateTransaction> ListingRealEstateTransactions { get; set; }

    public Virtual ICollection<RealEstateTransaction> SellingRealEstateTransactions { get; set; }
}

public class RealEstateTransaction
{
    public long RealEstateTransactionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ListingAgentId")]
    public Agent ListingAgent { get; set; }
    public long ListingAgentId { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("SellingAgentId ")]
    public Agent SellingAgent { get; set; }
    public long SellingAgentId { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Isn't the ForeignKey attribute implied by the naming syntax?

Comment: @JED no . you should use DataAnnotation or FluentApi  to define ForingKey manualy